# Using cron value from properties file in spring scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using the Spring Schedular in my Spring Boot Application. I have defined the cron expression a properties file:

```
batch.delete-job.cron=0 0 0 * * *
```

I am using this value in my method annoated with the @Scheduled Annotation as follows:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${batch.delete-job.cron}")
public void doBatchJob() {

}
```

I keep on getting the error messsage:

Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'doBatchJob': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in "${batch.delete-job.cron}")

If I use the cron expression directly in annotation, then it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `@Scheduled(cron = "${batch.deleteJob.cron}")`, even though the name in the property file is `batch.delete-job.cron`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Application Context-

```
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
       return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

If this dosent work try removing the hyphen in both the places(Your code and the application properties and seperate by .)
For Eg-${batch.delete.job.cron}

Answer (score 0):

Removing the hypen from the property name made no difference,but I did it anyway. What solved the problem was to put the following annotation referencing the properties file on my class containing the doBatchJob() method. The working solution looks as folllows:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/config.properties")
@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class DeleteBatch {

  @Scheduled(cron = "${batch.delete.job.cron}")
  public void doBatchJob() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CRON is a widely used feature,  but one of its disadvantages is poor readability. If a non-programmer needs to set a property that defines the scheduling it would be a challenging task. Imagine if you could write something like this: `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 9h)` for scheduling the job for every 9 hours (or moving "9h" into properties file). Well, I wrote my own feature that allows you to do just that. See the explanation [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/backgroundrunner/package-summary.html). This feature is available in MgntUtis open source library. The library is available as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) or from [Git](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases). Using this feature requires writing a bit more code then just using annotation, but provides a user-friendly format. So it is a trade-ff

Answer (score 0):

For those of you, using

> application.yml

First set the cron property into application.yml file.

```
scheduler:
   cron: '0 0 0 * * *'
```

- Note: Set the value of the cron expression within the single quote.

Then it can be used with as value for cron to the Scheduled argument.

For example:

Instead of:

```
@Scheduled(cron = “0 0 0 * * *”)
public void scheduledJob() {
   System.out.println("Scheduled job has been executed")
}
```

You can use:

```
@Scheduled(cron = “${scheduler.cron}”)
public void scheduledJob() {
   System.out.println("Scheduled job has been executed")
}
```